# Python Threading: "RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-multithreading, turtle-graphics

I am making a ping pong game with turtle. However, the assignment is that code must have multithreading. I could not apply multithreading properly.

The code shows no error in the editor, but it does not work. How can we fix this runtime error? It is so hard to find the error when there is no error in the editor.

```
import turtle
from threading import *
from time import sleep

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Ping pong by Cagatay em")
wn.bgcolor("blue")
wn.setup(width=900, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)  #oyunu hizlandirir silersen cok yavaslar 

class PaddleFirst(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pen = turtle.Turtle()
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.speed(0)
        self.pen.shape("square")
        self.pen.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(-350, 0)

    def run(self):
        y = self.pen.ycor()
        y += 20
        self.pen.sety(y)
        k = self.pen.ycor()
        k -= 20
        self.pen.sety(k)


class PaddleSecond(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pen = turtle.Turtle()
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.speed(0)
        self.pen.shape("square")
        self.pen.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(350, 0)

    def run(self):
        y = self.pen.ycor()
        y += 20
        self.pen.sety(y)
        k = self.pen.ycor()
        k -= 20
        self.pen.sety(k)



class Ball(Thread):
    def __init__(self):

        self.pen = turtle.Turtle()
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.speed(0)
        self.pen.shape("circle")
        self.pen.color("red")
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(0, 0)
        self.pen.dx = 00.1
        self.pen.dy = 00.1

    def run(self):
        self.pen.setx(self.pen.xcor() + self.pen.dx)
        self.pen.sety(self.pen.ycor() + self.pen.dy)
        if self.pen.ycor() > 290:
            self.pen.sety(290)
            self.pen.dy *= -1

        if self.pen.ycor() < -290:
            self.pen.sety(-290)
            self.pen.dy *= -1

        if self.pen.xcor() > 390:
            self.pen.goto(0, 0)
            self.pen.dx *= -1

        if self.pen.xcor() < -390:
            self.pen.goto(0, 0)
            self.pen.dx *= -1


class Wall(Thread):
   def run(self):
        if ball.pen.xcor() > 340 and (ball.pen.ycor() < paddle2.pen.ycor() + 40 and ball.pen.ycor() > paddle2.pen.ycor() - 40):
           ball.pen.dx *= -1
        if ball.pen.xcor() < -340 and (ball.pen.ycor() < paddle1.pen.ycor() + 40 and ball.pen.ycor() > paddle1.pen.ycor() - 40):
            ball.pen.dx *= -1


paddle1 = PaddleFirst()

paddle2 = PaddleSecond()

ball = Ball()

wall = Wall()


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle1.run, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle1.run(), "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle2.run(), "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle2.run, "Down")



while True:
    wn.update() # everytime uptades the screen
    ball.start()
    sleep(0.2)
    wall.start()
    sleep(0.2)
    paddle1.start()
    sleep(0.2)
    paddle2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error message you got is due to you not calling the super class' `__init__()` method in your subclass of `Thread`.

> It is so hard to find the error when there is no error in the editor.

You need to learn the art of debugging.

> i could not apply multithreading properly.

I think there are two issues here.  First, to use threading with turtle, which is built atop tkinter, you need to have all graphics commands routed throught the main thread -- secondary threads shouldn't try to modify the screen directly.

Second, your code is a mess.  Aside from threading, it's not clear you understand object-programming as you have two *identical* classes, except for an X coordinate.  This should be one class with an argument to it's initializer.  It's not clear you undertand turtle as `wn.onkeypress(paddle1.run(), "s")` will never work.  You probably shouldn't be messing with `tracer()` and `update()` until your code is working.  And you shouldn't have a `while True:` on the main turtle thread.

I've taken your code apart and put it back together below.  Only the ball is a separate thread, the (single) paddle class now inherits from `Turtle`.  The main thread processes graphics commands from the ball thread as well as standard turtle events:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from threading import Thread, active_count
from queue import Queue

QUEUE_SIZE = 1

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, xcor):
        super().__init__(shape='square')

        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.penup()
        self.setx(xcor)
        self.dy = 10

    def down(self):
        y = self.ycor() - self.dy

        if y > -250:
            self.sety(y)

    def up(self):
        y = self.ycor() + self.dy

        if y < 250:
            self.sety(y)

class Ball(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)

        self.pen = Turtle('circle')
        self.pen.speed('fastest')
        self.pen.color('red')
        self.pen.penup()
        self.dx = 1
        self.dy = 1

    def run(self):
        x, y = self.pen.position()

        while True:
            x += self.dx
            y += self.dy

            if x > 330 and (paddle2.ycor() - 60 < y < paddle2.ycor() + 60):
                self.dx *= -1
            elif x < -330 and (paddle1.ycor() - 60 < y < paddle1.ycor() + 60):
                self.dx *= -1

            if y > 290:
                y = 290
                self.dy *= -1
            elif y < -290:
                y = -290
                self.dy *= -1
            elif not -440 < x < 440:
                x, y = 0, 0
                self.dx *= -1

            actions.put((self.pen.setposition, x, y))

def process_queue():
    while not actions.empty():
        action, *arguments = actions.get()
        action(*arguments)

    if active_count() > 1:
        screen.ontimer(process_queue, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Ping pong rework by cdlane")
screen.bgcolor('blue')
screen.setup(width=900, height=600)

actions = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)

paddle1 = Paddle(-350)
paddle2 = Paddle(350)
ball = Ball()

screen.onkeypress(paddle1.up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle1.down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(paddle2.up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(paddle2.down, 'Down')
screen.listen()

ball.start()

process_queue()

screen.mainloop()
```

The code is still incomplete and slightly buggy (e.g. doesn't shut down cleanly) -- things for you to work on.  But it basically plays the game in a reasonable fashion.

Comment: How can I make this game in such a way that 2 players can play at the same time? i want to be able to hold "w" and "up' button at the same time.

Comment: @RodionRaskolnikov, although making the paddles threads might be necessary to do this, my guess is it won't be sufficient.  The high level access that you get to the keyboard by default isn't likely going to handle fast multiple keys at the same time.  For this you'll likely need a lower level interface to the keyboard like [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html) or some such.  Alternatively, consider pitting a single player against the computer.